# Proving coinductive theorems with coinductive assumptions

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coinduction

I have a simple lazy binary tree implementation:

```ml
CoInductive LTree (A : Set) : Set :=
| LLeaf : LTree A
| LBin : A -> (LTree A) -> (LTree A) -> LTree A.
```

And following properties:

```ml
(* Having some infinite branch *)

CoInductive SomeInfinite {A} : LTree A -> Prop :=
  SomeInfinite_LBin :
    forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), (SomeInfinite l \/ SomeInfinite r) ->
      SomeInfinite (LBin _ a l r).

(* Having only finite branches (i.e. being finite) *)

Inductive AllFinite {A} : LTree A -> Prop :=
  | AllFinite_LLeaf : AllFinite (LLeaf A)
  | AllFinite_LBin :
      forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), (AllFinite l /\ AllFinite r) ->
                                 AllFinite (LBin _ a l r).
```

I would like to prove a theorem that states that a finite tree does not have any infinite branches:

```ml
Theorem allfinite_noinfinite : forall {A} (t : LTree A), AllFinite t -> not (SomeInfinite t).
```

...but I got lost after first few tactics. The hypothesis itself seems pretty trivial, but I cannot even start with it. What would proving of such a theorem look like?

Answer (score 2):

The proof is actually not difficult (but you stumbled upon some annoying quirks): to start, the main idea of the proof is that you have an inductive witness that `t` is finite, so you can do an induction on that witness concluding with a contradiction when `t` is just a leaf and reusing the inductive hypothesis when it is a binary node.

Now the annoying problem is that Coq does not derive the right induction principle for `AllFinite` because of `/\` : compare

```
Inductive AllFinite {A} : LTree A -> Prop :=
  | AllFinite_LLeaf : AllFinite (LLeaf A)
  | AllFinite_LBin :
      forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), AllFinite l /\ AllFinite r ->
                                 AllFinite (LBin _ a l r).
Check AllFinite_ind.
(* AllFinite_ind *)
(*      : forall (A : Set) (P : LTree A -> Prop), *)
(*        P (LLeaf A) -> *)
(*        (forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), *)
(*         AllFinite l /\ AllFinite r -> P (LBin A a l r)) -> *)
(*        forall l : LTree A, AllFinite l -> P l *)
```

with

```
Inductive AllFinite' {A} : LTree A -> Prop :=
  | AllFinite'_LLeaf : AllFinite' (LLeaf A)
  | AllFinite'_LBin :
      forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), AllFinite' l -> AllFinite' r ->
                                 AllFinite' (LBin _ a l r).
Check AllFinite'_ind.
(* AllFinite'_ind *)
(*      : forall (A : Set) (P : LTree A -> Prop), *)
(*        P (LLeaf A) -> *)
(*        (forall (a : A) (l r : LTree A), *)
(*         AllFinite' l -> P l -> AllFinite' r -> P r -> P (LBin A a l r)) -> *)
(*        forall l : LTree A, AllFinite' l -> P l *)
```

In the inductive case, the first version does not give you the expected inductive hypothesis. So either you can change your `AllFinite` to `AllFInite'`, or you need to reprove the induction principle by hand.